# How do I convert (or cast) Fedex shipping request types into rate request types in C#?

Tags: c#, fedex

So here's the problem: I have written an application to call the Fedex **shipping** API, but now I also need to make a separate **rate** request immediately after the shipping request. (The reason is that I need a non-account rate for data and metrics, but I don't get any rates for third-party shipment requests). When I create the rate request, I *can* do something like this for simple values:

```
raterequest.RequestedShipment.ServiceType = (rateReference.ServiceType)shiprequest.RequestedShipment.ServiceType;
```

But I can *not* do this with any complex types, like this:

```
raterequest.RequestedShipment.Shipper = (rateReference.Shipper)shiprequest.RequestedShipment.Shipper;
```

Or even like this:

```
raterequest.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Address = (rateReference.Address)shiprequest.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Address;
```

... because .Net will complain that it can't convert between the ship Address type and the rate Address type (though they are identical). I can set the "raterequest" parameters one at a time (i.e. "Address.City"), but it's a hassle AND I eventually want to do something more sophisticated (i.e. call multiple APIs using the same request parameters with minimal additional code). Is there any generic solution to this, so that identical complex types (but in different namespaces) can be converted back and forth?

Comment: Are you sure they are the same type? I'm not familiar with the .NET wrapper they expose to you, but it's entirely possible they have two different types with the same name in two different namespaces.

Comment: More information is required.  For instance what is the difference between `RequestedShipment.Shipper` and `rateReference.Shipper` and why can't you just directly use `raterequest.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Address` as this I don't see anyone could answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound, because I was looking for a generic solution for complex type conversion. I'll edit this into my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is good at this kind of thing.  It generally does the "sensible" thing when copying from one type to another, and when it isn't doing the sensible thing (or something nonsensical is required) you can hook that and define what should happen.

Comment: This looks really promising. I'll look into this. Thanks.

Comment: This is the most promising solution I've found so far, so I'm marking this as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could define custom [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) cast operators to convert between similar raterequest and shiprequest classes.

Comment: I was hoping for something general. Plus the classes are created from a WSDL, so writing things that depend on those classes is a bit fragile.